# Cannot access my SQL Server database in my website using IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, iis-7

My connection string is correct. It works when I debug and run from inside Visual Studio.

My problem is that I need to browse my site from the IIS to be able to access my website from any PC in my network.

When I changed the application pool identity to `localsystem`, it worked. I am worried that it won't work on any PC in my network, because I have no means to test it.

Can you confirm whether or not it would work?

Comment: How you access it from local pc and machine on network show us urls

Comment: Have you tried and checked, whether its working or not...??

Comment: Even if you're convinced it's correct - can you please **show us** your connection string that you use?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are connecting using windows authentication - ie: "Trusted Connection".

That is why you can connect using Visual Studio - you are using your credentials to connect.

You need to run or impersonate IIS with an account that can connect to SQL Server, or allow IIS to impersonate the connected user, assuming they also have SQL server connection permissions.

Comment: @vinu: ... and we would be able to **see that** if the OP would **show us** the actual connection string he's using .....

Comment: It is mySql server. I don't think it allows connecting with windows authentication.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul No, I think it is "his" SQL Server 2008

Comment: @podiluska: How can I run or impersonate IIS with an account that can connect to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add user name and password in your connection string
like this

```
Data Source='server IP';Initial Catalog='database name';Persist Security Info=True;User ID='your user name';password='your password
```